# Adding new elements to a Set

Tags: set, append, julia

How to append a new element to a Set in Julia? For an Array this can be done with append

```
A = [1, 2, 3] # Array
S = Set(A)    # Set

append!(A, 4) # Works
append!(S, 4) # Does not work
```

Comment: You should use `push!`, rather than `append!`, both for arrays and for sets.

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you explain why? I always used append! for arrays as it works without complains. Also a benchmark test provides identical results.

Comment: The difference is that if you try to push/append a collection (for example `[1,2]`) one will add the collection as a single element, while the other will add each element individually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `push!` for an unsorted collection

```
julia> S = Set([1, 2, 3])
Set{Int64} with 3 elements:
  2
  3
  1

julia> push!(S, 4)
Set{Int64} with 4 elements:
  4
  2
  3
  1
```